# Installing only security updates is a mistake?

Tags: debian, security

On my Debian, I only do security updates:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
```

For example, Debian recently migrated from 10.3 to 10.4, but I still use version 10.3 and automatically install available security updates.

Is that enough for security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it’s not enough for security: in the run-up to a point-release, some upgrades which include security fixes (notably, the kernel) are pushed to the main repository as part of the point-release, not to the security repository.